# How to expire a link?

Tags: asp.net

> I have an app that send a hyperlink via email to allow users to get to a certion webform...

mmMail.Body = "http://localhost/mypage.aspx>
when a user recieves this link . Is there any way to add code to expire this link after 24 hours of user accepting the link. 
** this recieving time will be different for different users and hence my link should expire after 20 hours for the user, who recieved the link befor 24 hrs.

Comment: You could easily keep track of that in a database. What have you tried and where do you fail?

Comment: sometimes we think so complex , we miss the simple solutions ... may be that's why you not get the point to store in db with time .... and check when user come through that link ....

Answer (score 4):

Store a unique ID for each user together with the time of creation (or: time of expiration) within your database.

Add the unique ID to the link as a query parameter. Check the parameter when the user calls the page, if it is expired, show an error.